# $n$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ - $w(v_1,v_2,\cdots ,v_n)=\det A \cdot w(e_1,e_2,\cdots, e_n)$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, determinant, differential-forms

Is not hard to see that for dimension $n=2$ we have, for $w$ a two-form:

> $w(v_1,v_2)=\det A \cdot w(e_1,e_2)$, where $A$ is s.t. $(v_1,v_2)=(e_1,e_2)\cdot A.$

I'd like to generalize this result for dimension $n$ and respective $n$-form (same dimension), but I am stucked at calculus.

Many thanks for any clue!

Comment: The induced action of $A$ on $\Lambda^n \mathbb R^n$ is by definition $\det A$. The rest is just churning through the notation.

Comment: Sorry, is my first time on diff geometry and I could not understand what you mean by "the action is by definition $\det A$". Sorry, many thanks.

Comment: It's just a result about vector spaces, independent of differential geometry. For any linear map $f:V \to V$ with $n = \det V$ finite, the induced map $f:\Lambda^n V \to \Lambda^n V$ given by $f(v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_n) = f(v_1) \wedge \cdots \wedge f(v_n)$ is by definition multiplication by $\det f$.

Comment: Great, I did not study exterior algebra before differential geometry, now I understood what you said. Many thanks! I'd like to bounty your answer if you'd like to post as answer.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!

Comment: As soon as the system releases the bounty. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite dimension $n$, and let $f:V \to V$ be a linear map. The induced map $f: \Lambda^n V \to \Lambda^n V$, given explicitly by
\begin{align*}
f(v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n) = f(v_1) \wedge \cdots \wedge f(v_n),
\end{align*}
is just multiplication by $\det V$ on the $1$-dimensional space $\Lambda^n V$ by definition. Translating that into the notation of forms gives the relation you're looking for.